# Restrict specific object key values with authentication in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an object stored in the Firestore database. Among other keys, it has a `userId` of the user who created it. I now want to store an email address, which is a sensitive piece of info, in the object. However, I only want this email address to be retrieved by the logged in user whose `userId` is equal to the `userId` of the object. Is it possible to restrict this using Firebase rules? Or will I need to store that email address in a `/private` collection under the Firebase object, apply restrictive firebase rules, and then retrieve it using my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Firestore document reads are all or nothing. Meaning, you can't retrieve a partial object from Firestore. **So there is no feature at rule level  that will give you granularity to restrict access to a specific field**. Best approach is to create a subcollection with the sensitive fields and apply rules to it.

Taken from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#allowing_read_access_only_for_specific_fields):

> Reads in Cloud Firestore are performed at the document level. You either retrieve the full document, or you retrieve nothing. There is no way to retrieve a partial document. It is impossible using security rules alone to prevent users from reading specific fields within a document.

We solved this in two very similar approaches:

1. As you suggested, you can move your fields to a /private collection and apply rules there. However, this approach caused some issues for us because the /private collection is completely dettached from the original doc. Solving references implied multiple queries and extra calls to FS.
2. The second option -which is what the Documentation suggests also, and IMHO a bit better- is to use a subcollection. Which is pretty much the same as a collection but it keeps a hierarchical relationship with the parent coll.

From the same docs:

> If there are certain fields within a document that you want to keep hidden from some users, the best way would be to put them in a separate document. For instance, you might consider creating a document in a private subcollection

**NOTE:**
Those Docs also include a good step-by-step on how to create this kind of structure on FS, how to apply rules to them, and how to consume the collections in various languages

Comment: Thanks! Actually a subcollection is what I was referring to, just forgot the terminology! That's cleared things up for me.

Comment: Awesome! Yeah, just wanted to clarify that because it was a nightmare for us haha. We hit usage quotas because of that silly difference :D